# Vim format Python code with Black and then force tabs

Tags: python, vim, code-formatting, vim-plugin, black-code-formatter

I'm using the [ALE plugin](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) to format Python code with [Black](https://github.com/psf/black). Black indents the file with spaces (it's the same case with AutoPep8), but I want to keep my tabs. So I wrote this keybinding to run Black then swap spaces with tabs:

```
nnoremap <leader>ff :ALEFix<cr>:%retab!<cr>
```

When I run this, it works, but when I run it again the spaces stay there, and when I run it again it works, and so on. I works for one time, does not for the next, and so on...

I tried this as well, but got the same result:

```
nnoremap <leader>ff :ALEFix<cr>gg=G
```

What should I do so that it always runs correctly, runs Black, then always returns back my tabs?

Comment: Are you auto fixing the files on save i.e. does your vimrc has `let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1` ?

Comment: @isAif No I did not add this setting.

Comment: This question should be moved to https://vi.stackexchange.com, however I cannot find a way to suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can surmise is that you are using the **auto fix on save** feature of **Ale**. When you save the file it turns your tabs to space as **black** doesn't support tabs and neither does **Autopep8**.

Autopep8 does seem to have some way to get tabs. See this [link](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/207#issuecomment-103960116).

You can check the GitHub for issue regarding spaces vs tabs in case of [black](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/47) and [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues/207)

Comment: Thanks, seems like the autopep8 setting does not work in 100% of the cases, but that's better than nothing.